# Can't import android project from git

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm trying to clone a repository from my github into android studio. When I import, I get two errors:
ProjectName.iml does not exist
app.iml does not exist

I checked the paths that contain both of these files, and they do exist. Also, after that, [I don't see the 'src' folder of my project within Android Studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giS4t.png). I tried switching to Android view, and every other view there, to no avail. I checked the repository it created, but won't show up in Android Studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a known issue in the IDE,

Close the project, delete the project folder which is being created by the studio, re-open the IDE and create the project from the root folder again.

It should fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by creating it from the root folder. I closed it, deleted the folder, and pulled it via git again, but got the same issue.

Comment: Not form GIt. form the IDE, create new project based upon an existing folder

Comment: Again, the problem is not related to git, its related to the android studio

Comment: Do you see the files on your hard drive in the folder after clone?

Comment: Yes I do, which option would I chose: New project or import project

Comment: choose: new project. import will look for the .project folder

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much. Kinda silly this issue even exists though

Comment: Can someone do an exact step by step process of this fix? I'm not fully understanding how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @CodeWizard Please Add some Details for Us Thanks.